# is it fine to use around 50 'and' operators in a single mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Will it not severely affect tjhe performance?

Or is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Thanx in advance...

**EDIT**
 its related to a table that stores around 70 fields for a car, and i have to match requirement of a user to the availability of the car

and performance relative to "if there is any better way"

Comment: Affect performance compared to _what_?

Comment: Perhaps -- and this is just a thought -- you could quote the query. Like it says in [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *"We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them..."*

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail if you want improvement suggestions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: its related to a table that stores around 70 fields for a car, and i have to match requirement of a user to the availability of the car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments on the question:

> its related to a table that stores around 70 fields for a car, and i have to match requirement of a user to the availability of the car

With that structure, then I don't see a reasonable alternative to using a bunch of `AND` operators. You could shard the table on major criteria and then only query the relevant table, but that denormalizes it — with all the unpleasantness (difficulty with reports, modifications, maintenance) that implies.

Until/unless you see a real performance problem, I wouldn't worry about it. If/when you do, you'll have data to use to compare other approaches.

Comment: thnx...i just wanted to make sure that Iam not using a wrong approach for such a requirement. Thnx :)

Comment: @NitinBansal: Have fun with it. :-)